# Simplifying this complicated Mathematica result using known definitions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplification

While solving a boundary value problem, I reached the following expression for a Fourier constant (`CC01`) after simplification using `Simplify`. The expression is still **huge**. Is there any way to simplify this further in Mathematica using some definitions I mention below (or without using them)

```
CC01 = (32 E^(
     w γ) (-E^(-w γ)
          pc (Ta - tci) δ (NTUC^2 + δ^2) Sin[α/
         2] Sin[α/2 + β] (-2 E^NTUH NTUH^3 ph α + 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH ph α^3 - 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^3 - 2 E^NTUH ph α^5 + 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^4 α γ + 
          4 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^3 γ + 
          2 E^NTUH α^5 γ + 
          2 NTUH ph α (NTUH^2 - α^2) Cos[α] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH ph α (NTUH^2 + α^2) Cos[
            2 β] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH^3 ph α Cos[2 (α + β)] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH ph α^3 Cos[2 (α + β)] - 
          2 NTUH^3 ph α Cos[α + 2 β] - 
          2 NTUH ph α^3 Cos[α + 2 β] - 
          4 NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[α] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[2 β] - 
          E^NTUH ph α^4 Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH^4 γ Sin[2 β] + 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^2 γ Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH α^4 γ Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[2 (α + β)] + 
          E^NTUH ph α^4 Sin[2 (α + β)] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH^4 γ Sin[2 (α + β)] - 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^2 γ Sin[
            2 (α + β)] - 
          E^NTUH α^4 γ Sin[2 (α + β)]) (E^
           NTUC δ Cos[θ] - δ Cos[δ + \
θ] + E^NTUC NTUC Sin[θ] - 
          NTUC Sin[δ + θ]) (2 δ + 
          Sin[2 θ] - Sin[2 (δ + θ)]) - 
       ph (Ta - 
          thi) α (NTUH^2 + α^2) (E^
           NTUH α Cos[β] - α Cos[α + \
β] + E^NTUH NTUH Sin[β] - 
          NTUH Sin[α + β]) (2 α + Sin[2 β] -
           Sin[2 (α + β)]) Sin[δ/
         2] Sin[δ/2 + θ] (2 E^NTUC NTUC^3 pc δ + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ δ - 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC pc δ^3 + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^3 + 
          4 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^3 + 
          2 E^NTUC pc δ^5 + 2 E^NTUC γ δ^5 - 
          2 NTUC pc δ (NTUC^2 - δ^2) Cos[δ] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC pc δ (NTUC^2 + δ^2) Cos[
            2 θ] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC^3 pc δ Cos[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC pc δ^3 Cos[2 (δ + θ)] + 
          2 NTUC^3 pc δ Cos[δ + 2 θ] + 
          2 NTUC pc δ^3 Cos[δ + 2 θ] + 
          4 NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[δ] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ Sin[2 θ] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
          E^NTUC pc δ^4 Sin[2 θ] + 
          E^NTUC γ δ^4 Sin[2 θ] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ Sin[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^2 Sin[
            2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC pc δ^4 Sin[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC γ δ^4 Sin[
            2 (δ + θ)])))/((2 α + 
       Sin[2 β] - Sin[2 (α + β)]) (2 δ + 
       Sin[2 θ] - 
       Sin[2 (δ + θ)]) (E^(
        2 w γ) (2 E^NTUH NTUH^3 ph α - 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH ph α^3 + 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^3 + 2 E^NTUH ph α^5 + 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^4 α γ + 
          4 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^3 γ + 
          2 E^NTUH α^5 γ - 
          2 NTUH ph α (NTUH^2 - α^2) Cos[α] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH ph α (NTUH^2 + α^2) Cos[
            2 β] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH^3 ph α Cos[2 (α + β)] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH ph α^3 Cos[2 (α + β)] + 
          2 NTUH^3 ph α Cos[α + 2 β] + 
          2 NTUH ph α^3 Cos[α + 2 β] + 
          4 NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[α] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH ph α^4 Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH^4 γ Sin[2 β] + 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^2 γ Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH α^4 γ Sin[2 β] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[2 (α + β)] - 
          E^NTUH ph α^4 Sin[2 (α + β)] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH^4 γ Sin[2 (α + β)] - 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^2 γ Sin[
            2 (α + β)] - 
          E^NTUH α^4 γ Sin[
            2 (α + β)]) (2 E^NTUC NTUC^3 pc δ + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ δ - 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC pc δ^3 + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^3 + 
          4 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^3 + 
          2 E^NTUC pc δ^5 + 2 E^NTUC γ δ^5 - 
          2 NTUC pc δ (NTUC^2 - δ^2) Cos[δ] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC pc δ (NTUC^2 + δ^2) Cos[
            2 θ] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC^3 pc δ Cos[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC pc δ^3 Cos[2 (δ + θ)] + 
          2 NTUC^3 pc δ Cos[δ + 2 θ] + 
          2 NTUC pc δ^3 Cos[δ + 2 θ] + 
          4 NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[δ] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ Sin[2 θ] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
          E^NTUC pc δ^4 Sin[2 θ] + 
          E^NTUC γ δ^4 Sin[2 θ] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ Sin[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^2 Sin[
            2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC pc δ^4 Sin[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC γ δ^4 Sin[
            2 (δ + θ)]) - (-2 E^
           NTUH NTUH^3 ph α + 2 E^NTUH NTUH ph α^3 - 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^3 - 2 E^NTUH ph α^5 + 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^4 α γ + 
          4 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^3 γ + 
          2 E^NTUH α^5 γ + 
          2 NTUH ph α (NTUH^2 - α^2) Cos[α] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH ph α (NTUH^2 + α^2) Cos[
            2 β] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH^3 ph α Cos[2 (α + β)] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH ph α^3 Cos[2 (α + β)] - 
          2 NTUH^3 ph α Cos[α + 2 β] - 
          2 NTUH ph α^3 Cos[α + 2 β] - 
          4 NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[α] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[2 β] - 
          E^NTUH ph α^4 Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH^4 γ Sin[2 β] + 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^2 γ Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH α^4 γ Sin[2 β] + 
          E^NTUH NTUH^2 ph α^2 Sin[2 (α + β)] + 
          E^NTUH ph α^4 Sin[2 (α + β)] - 
          E^NTUH NTUH^4 γ Sin[2 (α + β)] - 
          2 E^NTUH NTUH^2 α^2 γ Sin[
            2 (α + β)] - 
          E^NTUH α^4 γ Sin[
            2 (α + β)]) (-2 E^NTUC NTUC^3 pc δ + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ δ + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC pc δ^3 - 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^3 + 
          4 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^3 - 
          2 E^NTUC pc δ^5 + 2 E^NTUC γ δ^5 + 
          2 NTUC pc δ (NTUC^2 - δ^2) Cos[δ] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC pc δ (NTUC^2 + δ^2) Cos[
            2 θ] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC^3 pc δ Cos[2 (δ + θ)] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC pc δ^3 Cos[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          2 NTUC^3 pc δ Cos[δ + 2 θ] - 
          2 NTUC pc δ^3 Cos[δ + 2 θ] - 
          4 NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[δ] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ Sin[2 θ] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^2 Sin[2 θ] - 
          E^NTUC pc δ^4 Sin[2 θ] + 
          E^NTUC γ δ^4 Sin[2 θ] - 
          E^NTUC NTUC^4 γ Sin[2 (δ + θ)] + 
          E^NTUC NTUC^2 pc δ^2 Sin[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          2 E^NTUC NTUC^2 γ δ^2 Sin[
            2 (δ + θ)] + 
          E^NTUC pc δ^4 Sin[2 (δ + θ)] - 
          E^NTUC γ δ^4 Sin[2 (δ + θ)])));
```

I mention below definitions that may be used but I failed in employing them using `Simplify`. The command kept running and finally spitted out the same expression. I have already tried some previous answers such as one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074801/how-to-perform-a-complicated-change-of-variables-for-a-polynomial-in-mathematic) but failed. Any help is appreciated.

```
u == (L/2) - (L/4) (Sin[2 α + 2 β] - Sin[2 β])
v == (l/2) - (l/4) (Sin[2 δ + 2 θ] - Sin[2 θ])
I1 == (L/α) (Cos[β] - Cos[α + β])
I2 == (l/δ) (Cos[θ] - Cos[δ + θ])
```